# pexpect spawn in a function

Tags: python, pexpect

pexpect.spawn seems to fail when I put it in a function.  In the example below, I expect it to touch both '/tmp/no.txt' and '/tmp/yes.txt'.  It only touches /tmp/yes.txt.  I've tried all of the obvious locations for the 'import pexpect'.  It doesn't throw errors, just doesn't run.  Thanks  for any suggestions!

```
import pexpect
def fun():
    import pexpect
    fail = pexpect.spawn('touch /tmp/no.txt')

fun()
succeed = pexpect.spawn('touch /tmp/yes.txt')

$ ls /tmp/*.txt
/tmp/yes.txt
$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for the command run:

```
import pexpect
def fun():
    #import pexpect you've already imported pexpect you don't need to import it again 
    fail = pexpect.spawn('touch /tmp/no.txt')
    fail.wait()

fun()
succeed = pexpect.spawn('touch /tmp/yes.txt')
succeed.wait()
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to matter.  In fact, the touch outside the function works fine without the wait.  Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: i guess the function was returning before the touch process finished